# Trying to install Python - excel read package

Tags: python, excel, installation

I am working on some data analysis with excel spreadsheets and I want to use python for some of it, so I tried to install these Packages,http://www.python-excel.org/, The write package worked fine but when I tried to install the read package with $ Python setup.py Install it throws an exception saying I need Python 2.6 or later - so Installed the latest version of python and it throws the same exception. Any ideas why or how to fix?

Comment: So i wrote a script to display the version of python being run, and what is displays is (2,5) so it seems somehow despite installing the latest version it is still running the old version - how to force it to run the new version on python? is there a way to uninstall 2.5 while keeping 3.3 intact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason write package worked fine because there are no version checking code in it. So its essential that you have to install python v2.7, because it seems write package use <2.6 code and read package use >2.6 code. To tie both end , you need only v2.7. So uninstall every python installation ( old and new ) and install v2.7.

Comment: I see, I don't know how to alter the path to point to the newer version so I guess full uninstallation probably works just as well. Thanks!